# Trying to initialize a linked list using array

Tags: c++, linked-list

I need to define a class of linked list,List, in a way such that object of class can be defined in two ways,

`List obj1 = L1();//head=0`

`List obj2 = L2(given_arr[], size of array)`  // I would be given an array, whose elements are elements of list

so, I need to form a construter for both,
for obj1, Its easy.
`List(){head=0};`

But I am not abe to do so for second type of object.

I tried to form a program for this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class List {
  class node {
   public:
    int val;
    node* next;
  };

 public:
  node* head;
  int arr[];
  List() { head = 0; }
  List(int arr[], int size);

  void addnode(int value) {
    node* newnode = new node();
    newnode->val = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
      head = newnode;
    } else {
      node* temp = head;  // head is not NULL
      while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;  // go to end of list
      }
      temp->next = newnode;  // linking to newnode
    }
  }

  void display() {
    if (head == NULL) {
      cout << "List is empty!" << endl;
    } else {
      node* temp = head;
      while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->val << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
  }
};

List::List(int arr[], int size) {
  int i;
  head->val = arr[0];

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) addnode(arr[i]);
}
int main() {
  int barr[4] = {9, 89, 0, 43};
  List* M = new List();
  List* L = new List(barr[4], 4);

  L->display();
  return 0;
}
```

This program doesn't work. Please suggest a way to do so.

Comment: Prefer a `std::initializer_list` for this task.

Comment: @sweenish I'm not allowed to do so.

Comment: Your list wouldn't store an array, you'd use the array to create the nodes that you need.

Comment: Yes, but how would I do that? I cant use std::initializer_list, as it is not covered in my course.

Comment: You know loops? Loop through the array, creating nodes as you go, and add them to the list.

Comment: I think I have done something similar in constructer for second type of object.

Comment: @sweenish you have edited my code and made it smaller :(

Comment: I have applied basic formatting to your code; aside from making it readable, nothing was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these changes to your `main()`.

```cpp
int main() {
  int barr[] = {9, 89, 0, 43};  // No need to specify size if you're initializing
  // List* M = new List();      // unused

  // Your array is barr, barr[4] makes no sense. You also don't allocate the List,
  // the list allocates
  List L = List(barr, sizeof(barr) / sizeof(barr[0]);

  L.display();  // -> to .
  return 0;
}
```

This now compiles, but immediately segfaults. Simply running the program in the debugger shows a simple error. The line `head->val = arr[0];` attempts to dereference a null pointer. Which takes us to the next thing. Use `nullptr`, not `NULL` or `0`.

Your array constructor was over-complicated, you just need this:

```cpp
List::List(int arr[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) addnode(arr[i]);
}
```

Your `addnode()` function already handled an empty list. Fixing that, your code should run. I made a couple other small changes, mostly trimming cruft out. Here's your complete code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class List {
  class node {
   public:
    int val;
    node* next;
  };

 public:
  node* head = nullptr;
  List() = default;
  List(int arr[], int size);

  void addnode(int value) {
    node* newnode = new node();
    newnode->val = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
      head = newnode;
    } else {
      node* temp = head;  // head is not NULL
      while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;  // go to end of list
      }
      temp->next = newnode;  // linking to newnode
    }
  }

  void display() {
    if (head == NULL) {
      cout << "List is empty!" << endl;
    } else {
      node* temp = head;
      while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->val << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
  }
};

List::List(int arr[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) addnode(arr[i]);
}

int main() {
  int barr[] = {9, 89, 0, 43};
  List L = List(barr, sizeof(barr) / sizeof(barr[0]));

  L.display();
  return 0;
}
```